# how to use cron tabs in yii application i want like email reminder

Tags: php, windows, yii, yii2, cron

We are running a yii apllication. I want to send reminder email to all those registered on my site 3 days before the event.

The registrant details are in my MySQL and it is a yii PHP website.

How do I do that?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first create `CronController.php` in your Project

> `folder/console/controllers/CronController.php`

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;
use yii\console\Controller;
use Yii;
use common\models\Appoinment;

class CronController extends Controller {
    public function actionExpire()
    {
        $expireDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));// current date plus how many days 
        // yor code select  email to all those registered
        $post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post WHERE date=:id')
         ->bindValue(':id',$expireDate)
        ->queryAll();
    }
}
?>
```

Customize query to your table and set email send function.After that set cron job this link help for setting cron job [yii2 cron](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2/)